# Moogose complex query joins

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, join, mongoose

I'm stuck with some complex query joins in mongoose (using nodejs)

I have the model User

```
{  active_payment: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Payment'}}
```

And the model payment:

```
{status : Number, creation_date: Date}
```

I want to find all the users with the a paument of a status = 2.
I've tried:

```
User.find({'active_payment.status': 2,}).populate('active_payment')
```

But its not working. Is there any way to do it without having to sort all the users by a for loop?
I would also like to sort users by the creation_date of the payment.

Answer (score 0):

You can not reach `status` in `User.find()` directly, Please try this one

```
User
   .find({})
   .populate({
          path: 'active_payment',
          match: { status: 2},
   })
   .exec(function(err, users) {
       users = users.filter(function(user) {
          return user.active_payment; // filter the user by active_payment field 
       });
   });
```

With `match` to filter the `status` is `2` populate documents, then filter `user` after populate though `active_payment`.